# How can I access the task dependency graph of a celery AsyncResult/Signature comprised of multiple tasks?

Tags: python, celery

I'd like to be able to extract the task dependency graph for a celery `AsyncResult/Signature`. My `AsyncResult/Signature` may be a complex chain/group/chord. I'd like to extract the graph of `task_id` from parent/children `AsyncResults` and serialize it so that I can reconstitute the `AsyncResult` from `task_id` string at a later date.

I suspect this output would come from traversing the `AsyncResult.children` or `AsyncResult.parent` tree of tasks, but wanted to see if anything in `celery` already existed for this without having to write my own traversal code.

I'd like an output something roughly akin to:

```py
{
    "GroupTask-id-xxx": [
        "Task-id-xxx",
        "Task-id-xxx",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like lots of the tools to use are discussed in [this answer](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4516) on GitHub.

Main tools:

- `Async/GroupResult.as_tuple()` gives a serialized tuple representation of the entire dependency graph. Used in conjunction with `celery.result.result_from_tuple(tuple_representation)` to rehydrate an `Async/GroupResult` from the tuple serialization.
- `my_group_result.save()` if trying to access `GroupResult` objects in the future from a single id. This saves the tuple representation to the bckend. Used in conjunction with `GroupResult.restore(group_id)`. Note that it does not capture the parents of either the group or its children `AsyncResults`.

If you want to save these results to a database so that they can be fully retrieved at a future date with just an `id` the following methods provide that:

```py
import json
from celery.result import AsyncResult, GroupResult, result_from_tuple

def save_result(result: Union[AsyncResult, GroupResult]) -> None:
    """Save result compute structure to backend"""
    result.backend.set(result.id, json.dumps(result.as_tuple()))


def restore_result(result_id: str) -> Union[AsyncResult, GroupResult]:
    """Restore result (including parents) from backend

    Raises:
        ValueError if result not found in backend
    """
    try:
        return result_from_tuple(json.loads(tasks.celery_app.backend.get(result_id)))
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError(f"Result id '{result_id}', not found.")
```